# Database Password with Perl DBI

Tags: sql, sqlite, perl, dbi

So I am creating a file on a server with Perl DBI. This file is created with:

```
my $dbFile = DBI->connect("DBI:SQLite:dbname=folder/databaseName.db", "", "desiredPassword", optionArray);
```

My driver is obviously SQLite and the file extension is `.db`. Later on I want to use this file in Visual Studio with the following connection string (everything will be on a local file so NO data stream to any databank):

```
Data Source=myfile.sqlite;Password=desiredPassword;Version=3
```

Basically all I do is to download the `.db` file from the server into a local SQLite file, but that works perfectly fine.

My problem is that I have no idea how to set a password for the database I create with the connection string in the code example. I assumed that it should just be settable in the `DBI` connect function that creates the file. However this doesn't work at all. So how can I set a password for my `.db` file with Perl DBI?

Comment: From what I can tell, SQLite doesn't have built-in support for password/encryption. (It does provide hooks so custom builds of it can add support.)

Comment: After some quick searching around on metacpan, there doesn't seem to be a module that uses any of the encryption extensions for sqlite that are out there (Sqlcipher, [SEE](https://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html), etc.)

Comment: There's a [userauth](https://www3.sqlite.org/cgi/src/dir?name=ext/userauth) module for non-encrypted databases using passwords, but you'd have to make your own version of DBD::SQLite that incorporates it and I don't think it stops versions that don't use that extension from using the database.

Comment: DBD::SQLcipher can be used in place of DBD::SQLite via this [dev release](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SIMCOP/DBD-SQLcipher-0.03_0019/lib/DBD/SQLcipher.pm), which can be installed with `cpanm --dev DBD::SQLcipher` until it gets a working stable release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no implementation of databank encryption in perl and apparently different libraries have their own implementation (there does not seem to be a standard for that) the encryption has to be done via the library which will later decrypt the password. My solution was to write a script in Visual Studio which will acquire all data from a database (or just a database file) and stores it in a sql file which will then be encrypted with the desired password.

So while there are some independet solutions for several libaries, there in no solution for perl DBI